# Oracle SQL query count of open projects grouped by month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am given a view to project data and was asked to summarize how many projects are/were open in a given month.

```
PROJECT_ID          OPEN_DATE         CLOSE_DATE         OWNER
         1          8/01/2012         09/01/2012          JEFF     
         2          8/08/2012         10/01/2012          JEFF     
         3          9/01/2012               Null          JEFF     
         4          9/12/2012               Null          JEFF     
         5          9/24/2012         11/01/2012          JEFF     
         6         10/01/2012         12/01/2012          JEFF     
         7         10/09/2012         01/01/2013          JEFF
```

I need OPEN counts such as this.  Once I get the basic query down, I'll need to filter/group by project owner

```
AUG12   SEPT12   OCT12   NOV12   DEC12   JAN13   FEB13
2        4       5       4       3       2       1
^        ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^
|        |       |       |       |       |       |-> From Projects 3 & 4
|        |       |       |       |       |-> From Projects 3 & 4 
|        |       |       |       |-> From Projects 3,4 & 7
|        |       |       |-> From Projects 3,4,6 & 7
|        |       |-> From Projects 3,4,5,6 & 7
|        |-> From Projects 2,3,4, & 5                                    
|-> From Project 1 & 2
```

**Latest**
This is what I have based on the connect by suggestion by Gordon.  The query is slow about 4-5 seconds

```
SELECT SUM(case when (OPEN_DATE <= thedate and CLOSE_DATE > thedate) or (OPEN_DATE <= thedate and CLOSE_DATE Is Null) then 1 else 0 end) as Open 
1.     From (select * FROM Project 
2.     WHERE Project.Owner = :owner AND Project.action_for = :actionFor )  
3.     cross join (   select add_months(last_day(SYSDATE), level-7)

4.        as thedate from  dual connect by level <= 12   ) 
5.      group by to_char(thedate, 'YYYY-MM') order by 1
```

Besides being slow, I'm not sure it is working correctly with my real data.  I need to decompose the query to give me results that I can manually check the results.  How does one debug a sql statement?  I mean just because you get results how do you know they are correct?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: How do you count a project that is open and closed in the same month?

Comment: good question. I think it would be considered closed.  I'll post what I have been trying, didn't want to clutter the question right away

Comment: `SELECT to_char(open_date, 'Month') as OpenMonths, count(*) as counts FROM Projects WHERE     to_char(open_date,'month') <> to_char(close_date,'Month')  GROUP BY OpenMonths` I wrote this as a comment because I didn't have time to test, but it may be similar to what you're looking for-may have misunderstood the question as well.

Comment: this is helpful, but not sure if comparing months <> not equal is providing the right count, since the data spans over many years

Comment: would replacing 'month' with 'MON-YYYY' help you? `SELECT to_char(open_date, 'MON-YYYY') as OpenMonths, count(*) as counts FROM Projects WHERE to_char(open_date,'MON-YYYY') <> to_char(close_date,'MON-YYYY') GROUP BY to_char(open_date, 'MON-YYYY')`

Comment: At minimum, Oracle (like pretty much every RDBMS) has `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions, so you shouldn't need to cast to character.  As a side note, I recommend making the query columns 'this month', 'previous month', 'month before previous', etc, and then setting the column names only at display time (if possible) - among other things, this means you don't need dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.  It puts the values on separate rows, rather than in separate columns.  I find that easier to work with anyway:

```
select owner, to_char(thedate, 'YYYY-MM') as YYYYMM,
       SUM(case when open_date <= thedate and close_date > thedate then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from project p cross join
     (select to_date('2012-08-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as thedate from dual union all
      select to_date('2012-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as thedate from dual union all
      select to_date('2012-10-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as thedate from dual union all
      select to_date('2012-11-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as thedate from dual union all
      select to_date('2012-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as thedate from dual union all
      select to_date('2013-01-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as thedate from dual union all
      select to_date('2013-02-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as thedate from dual
     ) as monthends
group by owner, to_char(thedate, 'YYYY-MM')
order by 1
```

If you want to create the monthends table for an arbitrary range, you could learn about Oracle's `connect by` syntax.  An easier way to get a bunch of months is simply:

```
select add_month('01Jan2000', rownum) - 1
from project
where rownum < 12 * 20
```

That will get the month end date for 2000-2019.

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand why the query has hard coded dates in it?

Comment: @jeff . . . You are looking for the number of projects in different months.  How else are you going to identify the months?  If you have a calendar table, then the hard coding wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: start in the first month that records appear, in my example Aug2012 and then roll forward

Comment: OK, I'm starting to see what you are suggesting.  @Gordon, is it possible to dynamically come up with the month end dates if I provided a start and end date range?

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow at work.  They want a rolling year so I can feed in the sysdate-5, sysdate+7. One thing that concerns me is the returning rows instead of columns.  I'm using JPA/hibernate. Won't know if this give me problems until tomorrow

Comment: your cross join seems to be working. I had to use TRUNC(Date) because the TIMESTAMP was throwing off the date comparison. Although the query takes 5 seconds.  As the table grows, it seems the query time will constantly increase.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the count of projects that weren't closed in the month that they were opened. This sounds like what you were asking for

```
   SELECT to_char(open_date, 'MON-YYYY') as OpenMonths, count(*) as counts FROM 
  Project WHERE to_char(open_date,'MON-YYYY') <> to_char(close_date,'MON-YYYY') 
    GROUP BY to_char(open_date, 'MON-YYYY');
```

The link to the sqlfiddle is here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28bf5/1 
I changed the nulls to other example dates because the text to DDL wasn't detecting them correctly.

Edit:

Using a generated month/year dimension, this query will work

```
   SELECT monthid, count(*) as ProjectsOpen FROM
  (
   Select * FROm table1 CROSS JOIN mdim WHERE 
  (to_date(mdim.monthid,'MON-YYYY') >= table1.open_date ) AND (to_date(mdim.monthid,'MON-YYYY') <= table1.close_date)
  ) GROUP BY monthid;
```

Where the month dimension is something like

```
     INSERT ALL 
 INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('JAN-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('FEB-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('MAR-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('APR-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('MAY-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('JUN-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('JUL-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('AUG-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('SEP-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('OCT-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('NOV-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('DEC-2012')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('JAN-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('FEB-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('MAR-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('APR-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('MAY-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('JUN-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('JUL-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('AUG-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('SEP-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('OCT-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('NOV-2013')
INTO mdim 
     VALUES ('DEC-2013')
```

Since the SQLFiddle screwed up the csv import, I'm doing some arbitrary to_date casting. But this second query will get the data you want if you populate your month dimension.

fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca8ac/34

Comment: Hey Scotch. Thanks. SQLFIddle pretty cool. But the output is not what I need as I show above.  I manually compued my values above but it should be AUG2012=2, SEPT2012=4, OCT2012=5 and so forth. You sql is producing 2, 3, 2

Comment: How would it be producing five for october? There's only two projects being opened in October

Comment: OHHH I get it now. You don't want the projected open `ed` that month, you want the ones that were open during that month. I'll have to rethink this.

Comment: Thinking about this, as @Gordon Linoff said, you would either need to add each month within the query or join it against a `month dimension table`

Comment: Since I am building this into a web app using high charts, I was hoping to write one sql statement and not have to maintain a dimension table or hard code Month end dates.

Comment: I updated my answer, finally got something working via SQLfiddle. If every month was accounted for in your tables, you could do without the dimension, but since you're looking for information on the gaps between data, I just threw together a quick MON-YYYY dimension. You don't need to do any maintenance, just run the script once and you can use it for whatever.

Comment: appreciate the effort.  I'm not a db guy, just trying to plug some results into my webab.  I'll look more closely at it tmorrow at work. thanks

Comment: sorry, your SQL Fiddle is not producing the results as I have above. Yours show AUG=1 open project, but there are 2 projects that were opened in AUG. So when querying "How many projects were open during the Month of AUG 2012", the result should be 2.

Comment: It's loss of precision on some of your dates from casting them. It should work fine when you implement this in your own system. I used text to ddl and got inconsistent data types (one of the fields is datetime and the other is timestamp if I recall correctly)